# Force any object to be null in F#

Tags: .net, types, f#, option-type

Objects can be casted in either direction, which is unsafe. How can I force any object to be null and use them in production code?

For example, in `Option<'T>`, I can now easily have 3 ways to make a nullable type: `Some (Unchecked.defaultof<'T>)`, `None` and `null`.

Comment: Can you provide more context? What are you trying to do here? How would you use the resulting null in code? What exactly do you mean by "Objects can be casted in either direction"?

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox an OCamler said to me about F# "an unusably bad type system" with the exact quote "the object system is broken and doesn't match the rest of the language. despite "not having null" it really does have null, for example. objects can be cast in either direction (unsafe)". Could you explain what he meant?

Comment: This reads to me as if he was talking about all the things that exist to support c# interop which requires F# to have null also. But that doesn't mean it's a good idea to use it.

Comment: Could've been talking about upcasting and downcasting. F# does have a compile-time safe upcast operator, `:>`, but it also lets you attempt unsafe downcast with the `:?>` operator, which can throw an exception. But for an unsafe cast you would usually pattern match with the type test pattern, `:?`

Comment: Take whatever OCamlers say about F# with a grain of salt, they can be a bit sour about the whole thing ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that what you're really wondering about is this quote from the comments:

> despite "not having null" it really does have null, for example. objects can be cast in either direction (unsafe)

Let's first clarify some F# terminology:

- "Nullable" refers to a type's ability to be directly assigned null, as in writing `null` where this type is expected. F# allows such types for interop with other CLI languages, with features such as [Nullable Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/nullable-operators), or the [AllowNullLiteralAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.allownullliteralattribute-class-%5Bfsharp%5D). Reference types defined in C# are generally nullable, so that an F# programmer can use C# libraries that use null.
- "Object" refers to pretty much anything, even value types, which can't be null unless they are additionally boxed – but I'm having difficulties imagining sane code that's dealing with boxed value types that were assigned null.

So, calling an option a nullable type isn't proper F# terminology, since you can't assign null to it without explicitly using unsafe functions. While options use null internally, this is usually treated as an implementation detail.

With this in mind, the quote you're wondering about is probably referring to the ability to assign `null` to any reference type in F#, with expressions such as `Unchecked.defaultof<MyRecordType>`. This can be used in a position where null would be invalid, effectively circumventing the stricter typing that should disallow null for a normal record type.

I think this is a fairly weak criticism, as using a function from the `Unchecked` module should alert a programmer that they are circumventing a safety mechanism. Doing this is rarely necessary, so this kind of reduced of type safety doesn't cause many errors.